A Probablity puzzle on exiting from doors.
A person enters at $A $(see fig.), and after reaching the point of intersection, he chooses a direction randomly (including the possibility of turning around). If the person reaches an exit then he cannot turn around. (From the respective junctions if a person goes towards either $A$ or $B $or $C $ or $D $ then he cannot turn around)

Let respective junctions be $A',B',C',D'$
Since there are infinite cases from $A'$ to $B'$ ($A'B',A'D'A'B',A'D'A'D'C'B'...$).
I took the probablity from $A'$ to $B'$ or $D'$ to be $x$, $A'$ to $C'$ to be $y$. And $A'$ to $A'$ again to be $z$.
So, $$P(A)=\frac{z}{3}$$ $$P(B)=P(D)=\frac{x}{3}$$
$$P(C)=\frac{y}{3}$$
And we have $$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+P(D)=1$$
Where $P(x)$ is probablity of exiting from gate $x$
Also, to reach $A'$ we have to go through $B'$ or $D'$. But I am confoused here due to infinite possibilities from $B'$ to $C'$ whether $y=2x^2$ or not.
Answer given in my assignment is,
$$P(A)=\frac{7}{15}$$ $$P(B)=P(D)=\frac{1}{5}$$
$$P(C)=\frac{2}{15}$$
Which doesn't satisfy my conditions.
Can anyone help me out?

The rules are not clear.  What does "But if he to go to gate form respective junction he can't return" mean?  As a guess:  if our man enters at $A$ and then moves to $B$, he can't return to $A$?  Ever?  He can't go $ABCDA$?   And what do the tunnels do?  Can he go from $A$ to any of $B,C,D$?   Or just to the two neighboring corners of the square?

I think the question must be that at each step the person is equally likely to exit at their current location, as they are to move to each of the adjacent corners of the park (i.e. each is 1/3), and they repeat this until they exit the park. The trick is to realise that the park is symmetrical so that after they move to an adjacent corner, the exit probabilities are the same as before, just relative to their new location. You can set up 3 equations for the 3 unknowns, and solve them.

@lulu no , if he goes to gate he can't return

@JaapScherphuis let me edit question for some more clarification.

Are you trying to say "he can exit the park at any one of $A,B,C,D$ and once he has done so, he can't come back in."?   And what about my other question?  If our man is at $A$ can he go to any other corner or just to the two adjoining corners?  You mention tunnels for some reason...not sure if they have any relevance.

@lulu I have editied and made more clear.

Your definitions of $x, y, z$ are ill-formed. If $P(A)$ is the probability that the man eventually leaves through gate $A$, $x = \frac{P(A)}{3}$ doesn't represent anything useful. It's not "the probability of going to $B'$ from $A'$", that's just $1/3$.
What you want to do is to consider $P(door, point) =$ the probability of eventually leaving through $door$ given that you are currently at junction $point$. Then you get a system of equations like:
$$P(A, A') = \frac{1}{3}\cdot1 + \frac{1}{3}P(A, B') + \frac{1}{3}P(A, D')$$
If you're at $A'$, the chances you will leave from A is 1/3 the chance of leaving directly through $A$, plus 1/3 the chance of going to $B'$ then eventually leaving through $A$, plus 1/3 the chance of going to $D'$ then eventually leaving through $A$.
$$P(A, B') = \frac{1}{3}\cdot0 + \frac{1}{3}P(A, A') + \frac{1}{3}P(A, C')$$
If you're at $B'$, you have a 1/3 chance of leaving through $B$ (and a subsequent 0 probability of leaving through $A$), a 1/3 chance of going back to $A'$, and a 1/3 chance of moving to $C'$.
You can also use symmetry arguments to show things like $P(A, A') = P(B, B')$ and $P(A, B') = P(A, D')$. So solving for $P(A, A'), P(B, A'),$ etc. become straightforward.

Why will probablity of going from $A'$ to $B'$ just 1/3? Aren't there several cases like A' to B', or A' to D' to A' to B' etc.

The probability of going from $A'$ directly to $B'$ in one move is 1/3. You need to narrow down what you mean by the probability of going from $A'$ to $B'$ via more than one move. The probability of reaching B' eventually given that you're currently at A'? That's harder to calculate and also not necessary for calculating "the probability of leaving through B"
